# How to write method for counting the number of strings represented of the concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list `data = ['aa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaaaaa', 'aaaa', 'qwer', 'qweraaaa']` in which I need to counting the number of strings from the list, represented in the form of the concatenation of two strings from list

My code:

```
def double_string(date):
    count = 0
    for item in data:
        if item * 2 in data:
            count += 1
    return count
```

I have 4 tests, 3 of them are correct and 1 is incorrect

Test:

[image: TESTS]

Task:

[image: TASK]

Comment: Your method does not cover the task. The task says "number of strings represented by concatentation of two strings" - this means two arbitrary strings. All your method does if only multiply each single item, you're never combining one item with another.

Comment: look at `qweraaaa`. You are testing `item * 2 in data`. But `qweraaaa` is `qwer` + `aaaa`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def double_string(lista):
    count=0
    for x in lista:
        if any(x+y in lista for y in lista):
            count+=1
    return count
print (double_string(['aa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaaaaa', 'aaaa', 'qwer', 'qweraaaa']))
```

Output

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you test the concatenation of a string with itself, and not all the other combinations with the other strings.

This code will work :

```
def double_string(data):
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(data)):
        for j in range(i,len(data)):
            if data[i]+data[j] in data:
                count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def double_string(data):
    str_count = 0
    for val in data:
        tempVal = val*2
        str_count += data.count(tempVal)

    return str_count
print (double_string(['aa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaaaaa', 'aaaa', 'qwer', 'qweraaaa']))
```

output : 4